# the label of the axis in matplotlib is overwritten by the ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I change the z axis label position of my figure. this is how my figure looks like. 
[image]

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d') # get current axis        
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
ax.set_xlabel('Intercept')
ax.set_ylabel('Slope')
ax.set_zlabel('Error')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the labelpad parameter:

```
plt.zlabel(*, labelpad=20)
```

or you can change it afterwards:

```
ax.zaxis.labelpad = 20
```

Play around with it until it fits your needs.